# Connect web app with existing Page for Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have created a web app that authenticates users on our page and I'd like to connect it with an existing Page, but cannot find that option. I only see "Create Page" in Advanced options, but that's not really what I need.

I figured since it is possible to connect an old app with an existing Page because of the group profiles being removed, it should be possible to connect *new* apps with existing Pages as well. Am I wrong to assume that, or just blind and did not find that option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure - this is possible.  
Please read the documentation for "adding a tab application to a page" at this link :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/
Essentially what you have to do is initiate a dialog so that you can choose what page you want to add your application to.  A direct URL example would be this : 
`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL`


Dont forget to substitute `YOUR_APP_ID` for your app_id and `next` to some other URL (doesn't have to be related to your application - it can be simple `facebook.com`

---

I have created a little bookmarklet to ease the prosess -

```
javascript:app_id=prompt("Enter App ID"); window.open("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id="+app_id+"&display=popup&next=https://facebook.com");
```

[More info on bookmarklets](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way/)

---

*We as facebook developers are solely responsible for keeping up-to-date with the changes that 3rd party API's, on which we base our development, make to their systems. 

A great place to keep updated on changes and new features would be the [Facebook Developers Blog](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/) and the [Facebook Developers Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap).*

Comment: Is this really the only way to add a new page tab application to an existing page or any page? It seems insane that this is so difficult.

Comment: It really is quite simple - I've created [a bookmarklet](http://pastebin.com/JXWky4g6) to assist in the process.

Comment: Why don't they just put this into the App Details section of the app settings?

Comment: Why is this thing so complicated? It's obvious that most apps wil have a facebook page...

Answer (score 0):

I tried the chosen answer but it didn´t workout..

***First option:***

You should use the **Fan Page Id** on the place of a random website.

http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=**YOUR_APP_KEY**&pages=1&page=**YOUR_PAGE_ID**

**YOUR_APP_KEY** -> You can get it from application settings, its App Id

**YOUR_PAGE_ID** -> You can get it through Graph Explorer (https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_NAME])

Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15739910/1598935

***Second option:***

1. Categorize your existing page under "App Page" (found under "Brands & Products").
2. Change your page name to mach your App name.
3. Go to your App and select "App Details"
4. Under "Contact Info" you will find "App Page".There you will be able to create a new page or if all went well, select your page from a list.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13904144/1598935