# How to link a Facebook app with an existing fan page

Tags: facebook

Now that Facebook has [depreciated the landing pages for apps](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/01/how-to--migrate-your-app-profile-page/), how do I get my app to point to the Fan page for it's landing page?

I've checked under the Advanced tab and contacts -- but there's no place I can see to list my Fan page as being linked to my application.

According to [this blog post from December](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/), new apps can create a new Fan page, but there's no information on how to do it for existing pages -- they just say that "it will be linked automatically."  Unfortunately it was not -- when you post something from our app onto your wall, the link takes you to our website rather than our Fan page.

I'd love for that link to take you to our fanpage again, but I seemingly can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: There was a migration option in place when this was announced but it's been finished since Feb 7th - why not just post links which point to your page?

Comment: Unfortunately I just started here and was given access today, so that migration option is no longer available to me.  We can post links which point to our page, but when you post from the app it prints out your app name.  That used to link to our app page, but now it just links to our site.

Comment: In now days there is no "App" or "App Page" category, is there any other approach to link existing page to new create app ?

Answer (score 216):

It is possible. I had the same problem. What you need to do is the following:

1. Categorize your existing page under "App Page" (found under "Brands & Products").
2. Change your page name to mach your App name.
3. Go to your App and select "App Details"
4. Under "Contact Info" you will find "App Page". There you will be able to create a new page or if all went well, select your page from a list.

I found the info in the little question-mark next to "App page".

Comment: Note: you can change the Category back to what you had previously once you've linked the page.

Comment: Yes, but if the category changes the 'go to app' link is no longer displayed

Comment: @Igy I was about to try this. Is there someway the 'go to app' can be retained with changing the category? Do you also want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106853) query of mine?

Comment: No, only App Pages in the 'App Page' category get the functionality specific to  App Pages, including the 'Go to App' link

Comment: I've two doubts on your answer. 1, How to categorize existing page under "App Page" (found under "Brands & Products"). 2. My app name means is app's display name ?

Comment: 1. Settings -> Page Info -> Category. 2. Settings -> Page Info -> Name

Comment: Before you start pulling out lumps of hair - as I did - go change your (personal) language to "English (US)". For non-English languages, some item namings make little if any sense, and some items flat out don't appear! Geez, Facebook...

Comment: this is not working for me. I am the app creator but not the page creator. I am just administrator in the page

Comment: @albanx it should work. I am app creator and page editor and it wored for me.

Comment: This works, you just need to go to Setting -> Advanced when you select your app to do part 4 which took me a little bit of time to figure out.

Comment: Changing the page name takes time. Can I change the app name instead?

Comment: The key is making sure App Page is the ONLY category. We had "Video Game" and "App Page" and this didn't work until we removed "Video Game." As an aside Facebook's workflow is insane--almost like it was written by a 19-year-old in his dorm room.

Comment: I couldn't even find the "App Page" category (Jun 2022)! Have they removed it?

Comment: In now days there is no "App" or "App Page" category, is there any other aproach to link existing page to new create app ?

Answer (score 25):

It is possible to add the application to any page you administer. This can be achieved from solutions mentioned below:

**Solution 1**

```
http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=[YOUR_APP_KEY]&pages=1&page=[YOUR_PAGE_ID]
```

`YOUR_APP_KEY` You can get it from application settings, its App Id

`YOUR_PAGE_ID` You can get it through Graph Explorer *`https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_NAME]`*

**Solution 2**

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=[YOUR_APP_KEY]&next=[REDIRECT_URL]
```

`YOUR_APP_KEY`  You can get it from application settings, its App Id

`REDIRECT_URL`  Any URL you want to redirect back to after adding the tab

**Official Solution**
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13904144/548854) from @Dvir Levy is the official solution from Facebook. The issue with that approach is that we mostly can not follow that solution. Suppose we had to add an application tab to a brand page like 'ABCXYZ', if we follow that answer then we had to change the brand page name, and we can't do it, brands/clients we work for doesn't allow these changes.

Comment: It works but how to list all the apps connected to the page?
I don't understand why so crucial option isn't accessible in visible place on app's or page's settings page.

Comment: im unable to guess it either :P

Comment: I've found the solution. List Applications installed on Page:
/[PAGE_ID]/tabs/
access_token: [PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN]

List of application managed by user:
/me/applications/developer

Comment: Is it possible to add the application if you are not an administrator of it ?

Comment: @LoverBugs No, you need to have sufficient permissions on the page to add/edit anything on it

Comment: In now days there is no "App" or "App Page" category, is there any other approach to link existing page to new create app ?

Answer (score 13):

Due the recent changes on the Facebook UI, some options have changed or are under a different place.

I would like to share the up to date way to achieve this.

#### On your page

1. Access the *About* section
2. Click on *Edit Page Info* on the top right side.
3. Set one of your categories to *App page*

PS: May be needed your page and app share the same name, but can't confirm this.

#### On your app

Access your app from the [Facebook Developers apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) panel.

1. Access *Settings* on the left side menu.
2. Set the category to *Apps for pages* and hit *Save*. [@JohnMc mentioned this has to be the only category selected.]
3. Open the *Advanced* section and find the *App Page* block.
4. Under *Existing page* select your page and hit *Save*.

All set!

Note: If you remove the link between the page and the app you won't be able to link them again.

Edit: As @John Mc pointed out in the comments, *App page* has to be the only category selected.

Comment: Great to see this. But why am I not be able to see existing page on my App Page after following all your steps?

Comment: There is actually no reason to show the link on the app page. If you want your page followers to use your app you can use one of the page-action buttons.

Comment: For me there is no existing page :( I can only create a new one. Even tough I do have an app page. Any idea?

Comment: I had the same. I couldn't get [Existing page] appear. Solution is to make "App page" category first on the list.

Comment: I tried keeping the existing category and adding the "App Page" category. I wasn't able to select existing page in Developer settings until I removed the existing category. I.e your existing page should only have one category and that needs to be "App Page".

Comment: Nice catch @JohnMc. ;)

Comment: Both the Page and the App must share exactly the same name. In my case, one had a space and the other didn't. In the App settings I couldn't find the page, as soon as I changed the app name, the page appeared.

Comment: "App page has to be the only category selected." This is very important!

Comment: @GabrielG. What if I remove the link? I did it without knowing I wouldn't be able to link them again

Comment: In now days there is no "App" or "App Page" category, is there any other approach to link existing page to new create app ?

Answer (score 1):

Happned to me. You need to add yourself (your developer account) as manager/admin of the page. Then it will recognize the link between you and the page and the app will show the app page so you'll be able to choose it.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible.

Go to you business page, add yourself as a managed (make sure you have liked the site first)

Then refresh the App Details developers page.
Select the business app page from the App page contact section.

Note the Business page has to be the Brands & Products : App Page, and the same name as the App.

Comment: Is it possible to add the application if you are not an administrator of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add a tab to a page.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

I use the direct URL Method. Go to your page and then type the following into the address bar of your browser.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL

Where `YOUR_APP_ID` is the app id shown in the app configuration page, and `YOUR_URL` is the page you want to to be redirected to once you close the dialog.

Comment: This doesn't change the URL that is linked to when the app posts an item to your wall and is for integrating our app into someone's profile.  That's not what the question is.  The question is how do I get the app in the Facebook developer app to have the Fanpage associated with it?

Comment: @Lix What is the purpose of the pagetab? Is there an example?

Answer (score 0):

In the Facebook app config settings will be Site URL.  This is the place where it's currently going, correct?  So have your marketing people make a "pretty" landing page for the app, and you can change your app settings to point to the pretty landing page.  Maybe all that landing page is a redirect to your Facebook fan page.

Comment: The problem is apparently you can do this for a new application -- I want to do it on an existing application.  f'ing facebook.

Comment: I have over 38 existing apps on Facebook (have deleted about 15 others as they've become deprecated over the last four+ years I've been deving for the various Facebook APIs). I went to one of the oldest ones I have and that setting is there.  How "old" are yours?

Comment: I have a site URL field.  But I want to link the existing application to the existing fan page.  This is not something I can do.  Can you?

Comment: As stated above:  "Maybe all that landing page is a redirect to your Facebook fan page"

Comment: Yes, I could do that.  But why when I make a new app I don't have to do that?

Comment: You asked "how do I get my app to point to the Fan page for it's landing page?" and I answered "Maybe all that landing page is a redirect to your Facebook fan page".  So if you don't want to do that, then why not create a new app for it (as you've pointed out that it works with new apps)?

Comment: No this did not answer my question. That is why I did not accept it. The question I asked was impossible to do. Hence accepting my answer which was correct.

Comment: It's not impossible.  As stated before, in our discussion, all you need to do is create a new app.  That is the answer, is it not?

Comment: I've one doubt. it may be silly, but my question is I created fan page using one facebook id and create apps using another id. Now can I connect those two app and fan page? is it possible?