# Can I link existing facebook page to a facebook app

Tags: facebook

I need to know if I can link existing facebook page (category: app page) to a facebook app?
When I go to the facebook app settings, they propose to create a new page. But all I need is link to an existing one, is this possible?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: It is possible (I verified). Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265062/how-to-link-a-facebook-app-with-an-existing-fan-page#13904144

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. You need to create a new one. There used to be a time period for migration http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/ but this is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The App Profile Page -> Page migration was available from 10 December 2011 until 7 February 2012 and was announced in several [blog posts](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/) and via a message at the top of all app profile pages during the migration period.

The tool for doing this was removed a few months later; if you want to create a new page and link it to the app you can do so from inside the app settings, on the Advanced tab:

[image]

Provided you leave the page category as 'App' there'll be a 'Go To App' / 'Play Game' link on that page, but there's no way to link an existing app to an existing page; it has to be done as a new page via the app settings interface