# How do I get the Facebook App Id for our page?

Tags: facebook, app-id

I am trying to find the app ID for our organization´s fb-page. when I try I get forwarded back to my initial page (the administrators panel).

This happens when i go to http://developers.facebook.com/ and then "apps". The same when I follow this link: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

The reason for me searching for this Id is that my joomla-platform is asking for it in order for me to be able to activate a like-button in my articles.

How do I get the App Id?

Thank´s in advance!

Comment: You'll have to create an application and only then will you be able to use it's `APP_ID`. However, you can not create an application with a business account. You'll have to create the application with a normal "personal" Facebook account.

Comment: @Lix is right, you have to create an app and then link to your page. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13904144/1515819) recently helped me to link a Facebook APP and a Facebook page.