# Any advantage in linking Facebook login app with Facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook

I am creating an ecommerce website for which I will have FB login supported. I also will have a FB fan page. While supporting the facebook login app, there is an option to attach the FB page to the login app (App -> *app-name* -> App Details -> Contact Info -> App page). The problem I am facing is that to connect the FB page, I **need** to categorize my page as an 'App Page' under the 'Brands and Products' category, and I don't feel comfortable in doing that.

Hence, want to know what advantages I get if I connect the facebook page to the login app?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not comfortable changing the category of your page, then I would like to inform you that it is not permanent. You can change the Category back to what you had previously once you've linked the page. You can follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265062/how-to-link-a-facebook-app-with-an-existing-fan-page) for more information.

The advantage of a Fan Page is that it provides information and updates to the users using your application. It is better to create a fan page for an app, than maintaining a separate website.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good. Igy [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13904144/235415) mentions that with re-change of category, the go to app link is no longer displayed.

Comment: Trusting the number Up Votes that AWinter received, I believe that I should work. :)

Comment: I felt so. You may want to have a look at Igy's stackoverflow profile. (Anyway, I need to test this out sometime soon)

Comment: Good luck. I hope it works for you. Do share your results here!