# open a link on facebook shared photo

Tags: ios, facebook, image, hyperlink, share

when posts are shared on Facebook, it says "a few seconds ago via CollegeParrot" which is great! We want to hyperlink the 'College Parrot' part of that statement to our Facebook page https://www.facebook.com/CollegeParrot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you need to:

1. Categorize your existing page under "App Page" (found under "Brands & Products").
2. Change your page name to match your App name, if it doesn't already.
3. Go to your App and select "App Details"
4. Under "Contact Info" you will find "App Page". There you will be able to select your page from a list.

See  also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13904144/1026226