# Linking existing facebook page to app

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an application which has facebook login. Whenever a user logins through facebook, my existing facebook page(I am the admin) should be auto liked. Is this possible to link my existing facebook page to the app which I have created in developers.fb.com?

Answer (score 0):

It's been asked before, you can try the steps from previous questions, it still works as of July 2014:
[How to link a Facebook app with an existing fan page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265062/how-to-link-a-facebook-app-with-an-existing-fan-page)