# Link a facebook app with an existing facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to find some clear information on how to link a facebook page with a facebook app. Reason being is that I would like to use the app access token in order to manage the page via Open Graph.

I have checked this answer [How to link a Facebook app with an existing fan page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265062/how-to-link-a-facebook-app-with-an-existing-fan-page#13904144) .. however I am unable to find "App Details" in my app page.

I found many ways how to do this, but it seems facebook keeps updating its interface and this information gets out dated easily.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can not use an app access token to manage to a page. Just use a page access token

Comment: Thanks @WizKid . After more research I kind of figured out a way how to provide a long lived page access token and use that.