# How to set up a facebook app for an existing fan page to track ad clicks/installs?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I’m trying to set up and link the facebook sdk in some existing mobile apps to an existing fan page. I’m an admin for the fan page, so I have access to https://www.facebook.com/analytics/page_a_id/ for that page. I want to be able to track ad clicks —> app installs. I got a new app working with the sdk setting it up through https://developers.facebook.com/apps/app_b_id/dashboard/. But I want it to be linked to the first page, not a new app. How can I create an app and link it to that already existing fan page? I have followed the instructions from this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13904144/419194), and I was able to successfully see the page I want to connect on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/app_b_id/settings/advanced/ . However, events from the facebook sdk on Android still are reported in the analytics page for `page_a_id`. Why is this? Is there anything else I have to do? Or am I just misunderstanding how this all works entirely?

And just to keep me sane, this is the correct process, right? I only want to be able to feed the sdk into the analytics. I feel like many other people must have done this, but there seems to be a lot of confusion from various SO/FB help posts.

Comment: The page needs to be categorized as App Page (somewhere in the page settings; you have to remove all existing categories, and then start typing until App Page shows up), and the name of the page and the app must match.

Comment: @CBroe Forgot to mention, I completed that step.

Comment: Are the ads you're tracking still associated with page A?

Comment: @CBroe yes //filler

Comment: So, what exactly is wrong now? You said they where reported for "page_a_id" ...

Comment: `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/page_a_id/settings/advanced/` does not make sense either; there is no access to any app dashboards via a page id.

Comment: I want the data (events) from app_b to be visible in the analytics page of page_a. It currently goes to the analytics page of app_b. Does that make sense? Is that possible? Also I mistyped that--I was able to select the fan page from the developer page for app_b. Will fix in the post.

Comment: App install events are events that happen "to" the app, that has little to do with any page. I don't think there is any build-in way to achieve what you want. You could of course create your own dashboard, where you read and combine/present insights data from the app and the page in whatever way you see fight ... but that's gonna require some work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150873/discussion-between-ahota-and-cbroe).