# Facebook messenger bot review process

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I need to replace existing company messenger bot with a new one. It is my first time when I am working with Facebook for developers, so I am a newbie. Could you help me and answer few questions? I tried to find them on the internet, but unfortunately, it is the first time I could not find something.

1) Could I deploy messenger bot from other developer application than current? I mean that I do not have access to current developer application, could I create a new app and deploy it to our page from that app?

2) Could I deploy new messenger bot without replacing the old one? If yes then could they coexist? I would like to choose users who will talk with a new bot, and the rest will speak with the old bot.

3) Do I need to submit my whole app for review? Alternatively, could I only review messenger app?

4) If I pass messenger bot review, then could I replace a fan page associated with the bot?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: 1) Yes, 2) Yes (but user won’t be able to choose - the incoming message will simply be distributed to both bots, how they handle it from there is up to them), 3) You need to submit the features you are using for review, 4) no clue what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me try to answer those questions.

1. Yes, the app is subscribed to the pages using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps. You can drop it and install another one.
2. Yes, there can be as many in parallel. You find them at https://www.facebook.com/[page_id]/settings/?tab=messenger_platform and it looks like this (below). You can also select a role (primary or secondary receiver), so that one app just snatches some sort of messages.
   [image: Installed apps]
3. Here it depends. There is "App Review" and "App Review for Messenger". I am assuming you mean Review for Messenger. Now, if the bot is pretty complex - which it is in most cases - you have to provide a video how to use it. So you are showing its features. First and formost for the "pages_messaging_subscriptions" approval, you need to show how to interact with subscriptions (adding, deleting, etc).
4. Once your bot (=your app) is approved, you can add it to as many pages you want. The review (sort of) checks if the app is a good piece of software, not on which page it will run later. Thats why you can add chatfuel to your personal, your brand or your fan page at the same time.

Hope that helps. Cheers

Comment: 1) Yes, but you have to be admin on the page.

Comment: No, to manage pages and their subcribed apps, you just need the edit_profile role (manager): [See the FB docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens?locale=en_US#roles)

Comment: You're right, the doc says it all. I based my comment on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15739910/4371822